# Changing the Title of a Web Part Page

Tags: page-layout, properties

I have a page that I am unable to change the page title from the file name of the URL. I'd like to be able to change the title of the page so it is something different. I've tried editing page properties, as well as the "Web Part Page Title Bar." Neither option works.

The desired output would be to have the title text be different from the URL. The page in question is a web part page on a team site.

[image: Unable to change web part page properties]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find any straight forward way of doing this. After playing around I was able to achieve this by executing below steps

1. Edit the page in browser and set the "Title Bar Properties" and set a valid Page Title
2. Edit the page in SharePoint Designer and remove following markup

   ```
   <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
       <SharePoint:ListItemProperty Property="BaseName" maxlength="40" runat="server"/>
   </asp:Content>
   ```
3. Add following markup

   ```
   <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
   </asp:Content>
   ```
4. Add following JavaScript inside `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">` and before the closing `</asp:Content>`

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(setPageTitle, "sp.js");
       function setPageTitle() {               
           document.title = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-pagetitle")[0].innerHTML;;
       }
   </script>
   ```
5. Save and refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks Amal. This should work, but I'd like other users of the site to be able to edit the title as well using the GUI. There must be a way to configure the master page so the Web Part Title bar option works, right?

Comment: @David I have updated my answer. Now try changing the title.

Comment: Will this allow me to use the "Edit Properties" in the GUI?

Comment: @David I found a workaround. Please try.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very roundabout way of doing it using GUI.
Click on Open Web Part Page in maintenance view (screenshot you've provided)

- Tick Web Part Page Title Bar
- Close
  Go to the actual page, the title bar should be missing now.

On the page

- Site Actions
- Edit Page
- Add Web Part
- Advanced Web Part gallery and options (bottom right hand side)
- click on closed web parts (left hand side)
- click on web part page title
- Add
- Within the web part page title bar hover mouse on right hand side of box. The text: edit title bar properties should appear. Change the name there > click OK
  [image: Close the web part page title bar]
  [image: Select advanced web part page gallery and options]

Answer (score 0):

I have found an easier way :

Just replace :

`<SharePoint:ListItemProperty Property="BaseName" maxlength="40" runat="server"/>`

By :

`<SharePoint:ProjectProperty ID="ProjectProperty1" Property="Title" runat="server"/>`